# Programming with timezone on shared server

Tags: php, mysql

Web application is designed for staff in Hong Kong but server is located in Head Quarter, USA.

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is set as default value to the field in database.

What is the best practices (PHP code) to fetch the time field from database and correct its timezone before showing on web application? Web application will also be used in other country with different timezone.

For example, time in record is:

```
2014-06-15 10:06:59 // fetch from database
2014-06-16 01:06:59 // to be shown on app if client is located in Hong Kong
```

Comment: You could just pass a timestamp to the front end and apply a date format based on where your user is?

Comment: Make sure your times are stored as GMT, set the location of the server in the php.ini so the USA offset is taken into account, and then the HK offset can be added in for users based there. Have a look at the `DateTime` module for this.